# Sessions in Web.py causing NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, cookies, web.py

Using session for the login functionality in web.py with python 3 generates 500 Internal Server Error.

Code:

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
# Session
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore("sessions"), initializer={'user': 'none'})
session_data = session._initializer

render = web.template.render("Views/Templates", base="MainLayout", globals={'session': session_data, 'current_user': session_data['user']})
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web.py-0.40.dev1-py3.5.egg/web/application.py", line 255, in processreturn p(lambda: process(processors))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web.py-0.40.dev1-py3.5.egg/web/session.py", line 83, in _processor self._load()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web.py-0.40.dev1-py3.5.egg/web/session.py", line 96, in _load self.session_id = web.cookies().get(cookie_name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web.py-0.40.dev1-py3.5.egg/web/webapi.py", line 487, in cookies ctx._parsed_cookies = parse_cookies(http_cookie)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web.py-0.40.dev1-py3.5.egg/web/webapi.py", line 447, in parse_cookies

    cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
NameError: name 'Cookie' is not defined
```

Comment: are you sure you have all the imports?

Comment: yes @MosheSlavin i only need import web and a few models

Comment: Did you update the package?

Comment: @VineethSai yes

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/UCL-INGI/INGInious/issues/208) thread can help you

Comment: @VineethSai thanks I'll check it and see if it helps